# complex number written in $re^{ix}$ form where $r<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> The complex number $\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i}\right)^{1/3}$ can be written in the polar form as $r(\cos x + i\sin x)$. If $r<0$, find the smallest positive value of $x$ in degrees.

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i = e^{i\pi/3}$. Thus $\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i}\right)^{1/3} = e^{i\pi/18}$. At this point, I feel like the answer is $\pi/18$ or 20 degrees, but I'm not sure about the $r<0$ part. How does that affect the answer (if it does)?

Comment: Always: $r=||z||>0$

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Some times in polar coordinates we allow $r$ to be negative. One of reasons for this is to find all intersections of polar curves.

Comment: @Qurultay of course, but then we type: $-r(cosx+isinx)$

Comment: So rather than $20$, should I say $380$ (although they're basically the same angles)?

Comment: @Helena Note $(r,\theta)=(-r,\pi+\theta)$

Comment: Oh I realised that it should've been $190$ not $380$. That also helped, thank you @Qurultay

Comment: Weird question.  So we want $e^{i\frac{\pi}{18}}= -\cos x - i \sin x = \cos{\pi + x} + i\sin {\pi + x}$ so you need the smallest $x$ where $\pi + x = \frac {\pi}{18}+2k\pi$ of $x =\frac {-17\pi}{18}+2k\pi$. For the smallest positive value $x = \frac {19}{18}\pi$ or... I guess if $y = \frac {\pi}{18}$ was the smallest positive for $\cos y + i\sin y = e^{i\frac{\pi}{18}}$, it should been obvious to smallest positive $x$ where $x = y+\pi$ would be ... well...$\frac {\pi}{18} + \pi$.

Answer (score 2):

First: I think the question is badly posed. Unless I'm mistaken, there's no reason to assume (unless you've a stated convention) that taking the square root and then the cube root must lead to the complex number with the minimum argument. All the roots are equally correct.

That said, your calculation of $e^{i \pi /18}$ is correct. Now note that
$$
-e^{i \pi /18} = e^{i \pi}e^{i \pi /18}
$$
to compute the argument when "$r$ is negative".

Answer (score 2):

You want the $e^{i \pi/18}$ in the form of $r*e^{ix}$, where $r$ is negative and $x$ is minimal?
$-1=e^{i\pi}$, so by multiplying it with $-e^{i \pi}$, you won't change it's value, so:
$$e^{i \pi/18}=-e^{i \pi}e^{i \pi/18}=-e^{i\pi+i\pi/18}=-e^{\frac{19}{18}*i\pi}$$
So $\frac{19}{18}\pi$ is the lowest positive $x$, since the period is $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

$z= re^{i\theta} = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$ where $r = \pm |z|$.

As $z = e^{i\frac {\pi}{18}}$ and $|z| = 1$ then $r = -1$ and

$e^{i\frac{\pi}{18}} = -1(\cos \frac{\pi}{18} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{18})$.

We are asked to find the smallest positive $x$ so that -$1(\cos \frac{\pi}{18} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{18})=\cos x + i\sin x$.

In other words words $-\cos x = \cos \frac{\pi}{18}$.  And $-\sin x = \cos \frac{\pi}{18}$.

Now basic trig identities $-\cos x = \cos(\pm\pi \pm x)$ and $-sin x = \sin(-x) = \sin(x \pm \pi)$. (All modulo $2\pi$ of course)

So the only case were $-\cos x =  \cos y$ and $-\sin x = \sin y$ is when $y = x \pm \pi$, or vice versa, $x = y \pm \pi$. (All modulo $2\pi$ of course)

So $x = \frac{\pi}{18} \pm \pi$  (All modulo $2\pi$ of course).

At for $x$ to be the least positive value $x = \frac {\pi}{18} + \pi = \frac {19}{18}\pi$.

.....

Note:  This reasoning leads to the identity that $e^{i\theta + i2k\pi} = -e^{i(\theta + \pi)+ i2k\pi}$ which is *very* easy to prove.  [$e^{i(\theta + \pi)} = \cos (\theta + \pi) + i\sin(\theta + \pi) = -\cos\theta - i\sin \theta = -e^{i\theta}$]

Has we simply kept *that* in mind the solution would be simply:

$e^{i\frac {\pi}{18}}= -e^{i(\frac {\pi}{18}+\pi)} = \cos x + i\sin x$ so $x = \frac {\pi}{18}+\pi$.

Comment: I have a question... I'm still not very familiar with this, so how can I determine what $r$ is ?

Comment: $r$ is *usually* the absolute value of the complex number. If you view a complex number, $z=a + bi=|z|$, as a vector it will have a distinct magintude, $r=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and a distinct angle,   $\pm\arctan \frac ab$.  Thus we can write it as $r(\cos x + i\sin x)$.  If $|r|$ were *any* other real value we'd get a bigger or smaller vector.  So $r$ *must* equal one of $\pm|z|$.  It's unconventional to choose the negative value.  But if you do, you must choose the *opposite* angle; the one $180$ degrees apart. So $z= |z|(\cos x + i\sin y) = -|z|(\cos(x+180)+i\sin(x+180))$ are the only two ways.